# Paperclip styles not created on upload, but are created on refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip to manage my image uploads  in a rails project I am working on.  It works perfectly for all of the models I am using it with, except one.  Styles defined in the model are not created on upload, but are created if I run `rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles`. For the life of me, I can't out what the difference is between this model and the others where it is functioning perfectly.  Here is the relevant code:

paperclip_attachments.yml:

```
:Artist:
  :sample_pic:
  - :large
  - :medium
:Event:
  :event_image:
  - :list_style
:Photo:
  :image:
  - :photofeed
:RecommendedVendor:
  :logo:
  - :feed
  - :larger
:User:
  :avatar:
  - :medium
  - :small
  - :thumb
```

model:

```
attr_accessible ... :image
has_attached_file :image, styles: { photofeed: "483x483#" },
                        path: ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                        url: "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
```

upload form:

```
<%= form_for @photo, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

<%= f.file_field :image %>
.
.
.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm wondering if these issues are related https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1265

Comment: I was able to downgrade to paperclip 3.3.1 and the issue was fixed for me.

Comment: Same problem for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's a keyword clash somewhere. If you rename your attachment from `:image` to something else you will likely not see this problem.

Having said that, this probably shouldn't be happening and if other users have fixed the problem by changing versions of paperclip you may have found a bug for the particular version you're using and should consider submitting it to [thoughtbot's github repo for paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)